# one line return condition

Tags: python, return, conditional-statements

that's my code:

```
d = {'key1':1,'key2':5}

def pop1(d):
    return d.pop('key2') if len(d) > 1 else d

def pop2(d):
    if len(d) > 1: d.pop('key2')
    return d

def test(a):
    return a, len(a)
```

pop2 works fine:

```
print test(pop2(d))

({'key1': 1}, 1)
```

pop1 doesn't:

```
print test(pop1(d))

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

What am I missing? Is it about the pop() function or the one-line condition?

Comment: `d.pop` will return something else but not `d` itself.

Comment: `pop1` returns the popped value (if anything was popped). `pop2` always returns the dictionary `d`.

Comment: see this: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/pop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we analyse the following return statement:

```
d.pop('key2') if len(d) > 1 else d
```

we see that when the length of the dictionary is less than `1`, the dictionary is just returned. This is not the case here, so we are interested when `len(d)` is `> 1`.

In this case, `d.pop('key2')` is returned. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop), we see that the `.pop` method will:

> If key is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value

...so `pop1` will return the value of `'key2'` which is `5`.

This leads to an error when you call `len()` on it since `5` is an integer.

This is made clear by the error:

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

---

Why does `pop2()` work?

Well this function does not use a ternary which decides whether the value or the whole dictionary is returned, instead we *always* return `d` - the dictionary.

This means that `len()` can always be called and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

when u do:

```
print test(pop1(d))
```

`pop1(d)` will return 5

so making your statement `print(test(5))`

`len(5)` --> 5 is not String , so you will get an error.